# I want to access positioning data from mimo beamforming. Is it possible to access this?

Tags: ieee-802.11

Modern wifi systems increasingly use beamforming to spatially divide the stream. For this to work, the radio must be able to calculate the relative position of the client.

Is there any way to access this data?

---

Clarification: I am trying to figure out if it is doable to track the location of wifi devices through this mechanism, and what approach is the most promising.

The only resources I found so far are scholarly articles.

Thanks!

Comment: It would depend on the model of the AP.

Comment: well - yes ... i should probably clarify

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade equipment are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: i'm not entirely sure how to phrase this - maybe you can help? by "more or less consumer grade" i don't mean 10$ usb sticks. but i also don't mean 1500$ lab equipment. would you think the entire question is off topic, or do you think i kind make it relevant by rephrasing it?

Comment: Consumer grade equipment is unlikely to provide the information you need in addition to being off topic.  Commercial-grade APs might provide this info through SNMP or an API -- something consumer devices lack.   Remove the reference to consumer grade and you'll be on-topic.

Comment: I don't thing it's doable because beamforming will only calculate where to beam, and not where the station is. If you have walls between the AP and the station, it will calculate where to beam to be able to send the best signal to the station (including rebounds) but it does not indicate the position of the station itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly? Not that I am aware of. It may be possible using open source (open-wrt or dd-wrt) firmware on supported devices.

Via API? Yes, Ruckus utilise data from their antenna when calculating client position. This data can only be accessed via API as the calculated x/y position not the raw antenna data. Cisco & Aruba have similar services. The Ruckus SPoT service requires extensive calibration in order to achieve a reasonable level of accuracy, AP position and density are major factors, as are environmental changes. The same applies across all vendors' solutions.

The methods used across these systems to locate wireless devices are broadly similar, combining signal strength, antenna direction and time for data to travel between client and AP. Acquiring this data for each client from multiple APs allows a position to be calculated.

It's hard. Most systems are only capable of resolution to around 10 meters in real world deployments, which is fine for some applications. Retailers were the first commercial users but aisle level tracking remains an elusive goal. Image processing from CCTV is one of the main competitive technologies but that too has limitations.